# Testcafe workflow for IE on Window on Github Actions: Error: The action has timed out

Tags: windows, testing, internet-explorer-11, github-actions, testcafe

After a couple of regression in our app undre Internet Explorer (IE11), we decided to setup a dedicated CI workflow to prevent them anyfurther. So we went with `testcafe`, but the setup is more complicated than with Cypress.
Currently my tests are starting but they got stock

#### Package.json

```
  "scripts": {
   "start": "node scripts/start.js -- --deploy=local",
    "test:ci:ie": "node ./node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe ie testcafe/ --app \"node scripts/start.js -- --deploy=local\" --app-init-delay 60000 --reporter spec-time"
  }
```

#### Workflow using `DevExpress/testcafe-action@latest`

Noting fancy here

jobs:
test-e2e-ie11:
if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
name: Run Tests for IE11
runs-on: windows-2019
steps:
- name: Checkout code
uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: "14"
      cache: "yarn"

  - name: Get yarn cache directory path
    id: yarn-cache-dir-path
    run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"

  - name: Cache node_modules
    id: yarn-cache
    uses: actions/cache@v2
    with:
      path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

  - name: End-to-end testing
    uses: DevExpress/testcafe-action@latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    with:
      skip-install: true
      args: 'ie testcafe --app "node scripts/start.js --deploy=local" --app-init-delay 60000 --browser-init-timeout 60000'
    env:
      NODE_ENV: development
      DEBUG: testcafe:*
```

##### Testcafe Step Log (using action)

```
2021-07-20T09:09:30.385Z testcafe:tested-app:stdout Compiled successfully!

2021-07-20T09:09:30.385Z testcafe:tested-app:stdout 
You can now view web-bot in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://10.1.0.132:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.


 Running tests in:
 - Internet Explorer 11.0 / Windows 10

 theme_04: conversation
2021-07-20T09:09:51.216Z testcafe:test-run:Internet Explorer 11.0 / Windows 10:driver-message 
    {
      cmd: 'ready',
      status: {
        id: '1330.243',
        isCommandResult: false,
        executionError: null,
        pageError: null,
        resent: false,
        result: null,
        consoleMessages: {
          null: [Object]
        },
        isPendingWindowSwitching: false,
        isFirstRequestAfterWindowSwitching: false,
        debug: ''
      },
      disableResending: true,
      allowRejecting: true,
      sessionId: 'dOloGSq4b'
    }

2021-07-20T09:09:51.267Z testcafe:test-run:Internet Explorer 11.0 / Windows 10:command 
    AssertionCommand {
      type: 'assertion',
      assertionType: 'ok',
      actual: ReExecutablePromise {
        _then: [],
        _fn: [Function (anonymous)],
        _taskPromise: null
      },
      expected: undefined,
      expected2: undefined,
      message: null,
      options: AssertionOptions {
        timeout: undefined,
        allowUnawaitedPromise: false
      }
    }

2021-07-20T09:09:51.271Z testcafe:test-run:Internet Explorer 11.0 / Windows 10:command 
    ExecuteSelectorCommand {
      type: 'execute-selector',
      instantiationCallsiteName: 'Selector',
      fnCode: '(function(){\n' +
        '   var __f$=(function(){return document.querySelectorAll("#bot-frame");});;\n' +
        '   return function(){\n' +
        '       var args           = __dependencies$.boundArgs || arguments;\n' +
        "       var selectorFilter = window['%testCafeSelectorFilter%'];\n" +
        '\n' +
        '       var nodes = __f$.apply(this, args);\n' +
        '       nodes     = selectorFilter.cast(nodes);\n' +
        '\n' +
        '       if (!nodes.length && !selectorFilter.error)\n' +
        '           selectorFilter.error = __dependencies$.apiInfo.apiFnID;\n' +
        '\n' +
        '       return selectorFilter.filter(nodes, __dependencies$.filterOptions, __dependencies$.apiInfo);\n' +
        '   };\n' +
        '})();',
      args: [
        []
      ],
      dependencies: [
        [Object: null prototype] {
          filterOptions: [Object: null prototype],
          apiInfo: [Object: null prototype],
          boundArgs: [Object: null prototype],
          customDOMProperties: [Object: null prototype],
          customMethods: [Object: null prototype]
        }
      ],
      visibilityCheck: true,
      timeout: null,
      apiFnChain: [
        "Selector('#bot-frame')"
      ],
      index: 0
    }

Error: The action has timed out.
```

#### Workflow using `run` with `npm` command

The last command is different, see the log.

```yaml
     - name: End-to-end testing
        run: npm run test:ci:ie
        timeout-minutes: 10
        env:
          NODE_ENV: development
          DEBUG: testcafe:*
```

##### Testcafe Step Log (using `run`)

```
2021-07-20T09:24:57.703Z testcafe:test-run:Internet Explorer 11.0 / Windows 10:driver-message 
    {
      cmd: 'ready',
      status: {
        id: '4626.4743',
        isCommandResult: false,
        executionError: null,
        pageError: null,
        resent: false,
        result: null,
        consoleMessages: {
          null: [Object]
        },
        isPendingWindowSwitching: false,
        isFirstRequestAfterWindowSwitching: false,
        debug: ''
      },
      disableResending: true,
      allowRejecting: true,
      sessionId: 'ZA8TILRDy'
    }

Terminate batch job (Y/N)? 
Error: The action has timed out.
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with my own test project, but I was unsuccessful. My test for IE passed in both cases with testcafe-action and without it. Could you please clarify if your tests work properly in IE on your local machine? If so, please prepare a simple project that can reproduce the issue on our side.

Comment: @DmitryOstashev I'm on Linux, that's why I want to setup the CI. The tests run nicely on Chrome. Can you contact me via twitter so we do a pair-programming session to debug ?

Comment: You can try to run your test on a Windows virtual machine. You can download it for free here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/. Sorry, but we do not do custom programming on StackOverflow, we just answer questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I explored `testcafe` in order to avoid the tedious task of installing and configuring my project on a whole different environment but still be able to test on IE11. I was able to configure it locally but unable to make it work on github action, either for Windows/IE11 or [Linux/Chrome](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-action/issues/24https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-action/issues/24). I hope you can reach the same maturity as `Cypress` as you offer opportunities they don't.